# Integral of indicator function

Tags: probability, measure-theory, functions, lebesgue-integral

I am thinking about an integral of an indicator function. The integral could be as follows:

$$\int_W 1\{x\in W\}dN$$

I am thinking of this in the context of a point process $\{x_i\}$ on the real line. Can I think of this integral as representing the number of points in window $W$, i.e.

$$\int_W 1\{x\in W\}dN=\sum_i 1\{x_i\in W\}$$

If not, does there exist a function $f$ such that $$\int_W f dN=\sum_i 1\{x_i\in W\}$$

Thank you in advance, and please let me know if I can provide any further clarifying information or if my question is poorly specified.

Comment: What is $dN$ exactly?

Comment: $dN$ is the counting measure, i.e. $\int_B dN$ is the number of points in $B$.